# Populating values to null column based on value of some another column from another row

Tags: sql, oracle, datastage

My requirement is pick `HIST_START` value where `status="CANCELLED" AND table="OUTCOME_STATUS"`. 
Put this value in `HIST_END` column where `table=("DOC_STATUS" OR "ENTRY_STATUS") AND HIST_END is NULL`
Eg. The first and second rows should have `HIST_END` as `12/06/2012` (which is `HIST_START` of last row.

```
ID          HIST_START   HIST_END    Appl Number    code    version STATUS   TABLE
10298337    4/06/2012                 1             I45     1   PENDING      DOC_STATUS
10298337    4/06/2012                 1             I45     1   PENDING      ENTRY_STATUS
10298337    4/06/2012    5/06/2012    1             I45     1   PENDING      OUTCOME_STATUS
10298337    5/06/2012    11/06/2012   1             I45     1   ADM_REV      OUTCOME_STATUS
10298337    11/06/2012   11/06/2012   1             I45     1   BAMERROR     OUTCOME_STATUS
10298337    11/06/2012   12/06/2012   1             I45     1   AWAIT_DOCS   OUTCOME_STATUS
10298337    12/06/2012                1             I45     1   CANCELLED    OUTCOME_STATUS
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Formatting could have been a little better..

Comment: what if there will be multiple `HIST_START` values with this requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the status="CANCELLED" AND table="OUTCOME_STATUS" will give only one row for each ID in this table.
But for safer side I am using Max() while fetching hist_start column value.

Then you can use following update statement to do your job -

```
UPDATE Table_Name t_1
   SET Hist_End = (SELECT MAX(t_2.Hist_Start)
                     FROM Table_Name t_2
                    WHERE t_2.Status = 'CANCELLED'
                      AND t_2."TABLE" = 'OUTCOME_STATUS'
                      AND t_2.Id = t_1.Id)
 WHERE t_1."TABLE" IN ('DOC_STATUS', 'ENTRY_STATUS')
   AND t_1.Hist_End IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Pratik your solution works perfect for me.

Comment: Hi again, The code works fine on the sample data but when i tried to implement on the full data (2 millions rows) the query runs very slow (almost keeps on updating for ages). Additional Columns used in where clause of inner query are ...  t1.id=t2.id and t1.cd=t2.cd and t1.ver=t2.ver and t1.seq=t2.seq and t1.appl=t2=appl. There are none index on the table. Which columns I should use while creating index , if indexing is really an issue in this case OR any other reason for slow performance. Please advice...

Comment: @Harry as you have described that you have condition on ID, CD, VER, SEQ and APPL columns then you can create index on ID, CD, VER, SEQ,  APPL, STATUS AND "TABLE" column for better performance.
I believe that there are some other columns also present in this table other than these seven columns.